# Which namespaces are the executable specified by `release_agent` executed in, when the last task leaves the cgroup?

Tags: debian, rhel, kernel, cgroups, namespace

Reading the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt) for Linux cgroups, I've come across the `notify_on_release` flag and how it relates to `release_agent`, i.e. the kernel runs the executable specified by `release_agent`, if `notify_on_release` is true, when the last process leaves the cgroup and no child cgroups exist.

How do I infer from this what namespaces the executable is executed in:

- is it executed in the root namespaces?
- is it executed in the namespaces of the process that created the cgroup?
- is it executed in the namespaces of the last process that exists the cgroup?

> 1.4 What does notify_on_release do ?
>
> ---
>
> If the notify_on_release flag is enabled (1) in a cgroup, then
> whenever the last task in the cgroup leaves (exits or attaches to some
> other cgroup) and the last child cgroup of that cgroup is removed,
> then the kernel runs the command specified by the contents of the
> "release_agent" file in that hierarchy's root directory, supplying the
> pathname (relative to the mount point of the cgroup file system) of
> the abandoned cgroup.  This enables automatic removal of abandoned
> cgroups.  The default value of notify_on_release in the root cgroup at
> system boot is disabled (0).  The default value of other cgroups at
> creation is the current value of their parents' notify_on_release
> settings. The default value of a cgroup hierarchy's release_agent path
> is empty.